# Dynamically show total per page, as I paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 3.2
```

I have the following in my invoices_controller.rb:

```
def index
  @invoices = Invoice.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], per_page: 10)
  ....
  @invoices_total = @invoices.compact.inject(0){ |sum, invoice| sum + invoice.total }
```

Here's the view (slim):

```
- if @invoices.any?
  tfooter
    tr
      td colspan="#{checkin_action ? '10' : '9'}" Total
      td style='text-align:right'
        '$#{number_with_delimiter(@invoices_total)}
```

This allows me to display the total for each page, in the footer. The problem, is that when I click on next, to move on to the next page, the total does not change. How do I get it to change dynamically with each page change.

Any ideas?

Comment: How you are showing total in the view?

Comment: The part in your footer showing the total is not reloaded when you click on a different page. You need to capture ajax success from pagination and reload the total.

Comment: @CharanKumarBorra: see my edit

Answer (score 0):

I updated my answer.

No need to write this query.

```
@invoices_total = @invoices.compact.inject(0){ |sum, invoice| sum + invoice.total }
```

I am giving logic to get the sum of `@invoices` show in the page.

```
#Declare a variable to store the sum of the invoices.
<% invoices_total = 0 %>

<% @invoices.each do |invoice|%>
  # While looping through your invoices add invoice total to that above variable
  <% invoices_total += invoice.total %>
  #Rest of your code for show
<% end %>

#Finally the Total Sum like this

<%= invoices_total %>
```

Comment: total is a column in the invoices table and is not a count

Answer (score 0):

In general, the `invoices_total` amount should not be changed, no matter what page you are in. The `invoices_total` can write this way:

`@invoices_total = Invoice.count`

Or if total is invoics's column,you can:

`@invoices_total = Invoice.pluck('total')`

Comment: Total is not equal to count. total is a column